# Java diagonal checking

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to identify number patterns in which a number is repeated 4 times in a row in a 2 dimensional array, i have came up with only identifying horizontally and vertically, could anyone please help me on identifying number patterns for diagonally and number patterns that occur more then once (either vertically with horizontal or vice versa) in a table of 6 rows and 7 columns

the number patterns are

pattern1.txt

0 1 0 3 1 6 1

0 1 6 8 6 0 1

5 6 2 1 8 2 9

6 5 3 3 3 3 1

1 3 6 1 4 0 7

6 1 1 9 4 0 7

pattern2.txt

0 1 0 3 1 6 1

0 1 6 5 6 8 1

5 0 2 5 8 1 9

6 2 6 5 1 1 1

1 9 6 5 4 1 7

3 0 3 3 4 0 7

pattern3.txt

0 1 0 3 1 6 1

0 1 6 8 6 0 1

5 6 2 1 6 2 9

6 5 6 6 1 9 1

1 3 6 1 4 0 7

3 6 3 3 4 0 7

pattern4.txt

0 1 0 3 1 6 1

0 1 6 8 6 0 1

9 6 2 1 8 2 9

6 9 6 1 1 9 1

1 3 9 1 4 0 7

3 3 3 9 4 0 7

pattern5.txt

0 1 0 3 1 6 1

0 1 6 8 6 0 1

9 6 2 1 8 2 9

6 0 6 1 1 9 1

1 3 9 1 4 0 7

3 3 6 7 4 0 7

pattern6.txt

0 1 0 3 1 6 1

0 1 6 8 3 0 1

9 6 2 1 8 3 9

6 0 6 1 1 9 1

1 2 9 1 4 0 7

3 3 6 7 4 0 7

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class petternrcognation
{
public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the filename : ");
    String filename = keyboard.next();

    File myFile = new File (filename);

    Scanner dataFromTxt = new Scanner(myFile);

    int [] [] pattern = new int [6] [7];

    while (dataFromTxt.hasNext())
    {
        pattern[0][0] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[0][1] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[0][2] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[0][3] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[0][4] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[0][5] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[0][6] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();

        pattern[1][0] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[1][1] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[1][2] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[1][3] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[1][4] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[1][5] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[1][6] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();

        pattern[2][0] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[2][1] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[2][2] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[2][3] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[2][4] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[2][5] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[2][6] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();

        pattern[3][0] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[3][1] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[3][2] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[3][3] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[3][4] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[3][5] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[3][6] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();

        pattern[4][0] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[4][1] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[4][2] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[4][3] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[4][4] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[4][5] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[4][6] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();

        pattern[5][0] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[5][1] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[5][2] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[5][3] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[5][4] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[5][5] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
        pattern[5][6] = dataFromTxt.nextInt();
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < pattern.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < pattern[r].length; c++)
        {
            System.out.print(pattern[r][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    if (checkHorizontal(pattern) == true )
    {
        System.out.println("Horizontal Checked true");
    }
    else if (checkVertical(pattern) == true )
    {
        System.out.println("Vertical Checked true");
    }
}

public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[] values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 3; i++)
    {
        boolean isEqual = true;

        for (int j =i; j < i + 3; j++)
        {
            if (values[j] != values[j + 1])
            {
                isEqual = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isEqual)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkHorizontal(int[][] values)
{
    int numberOfRows = 6;
    int numberOfColumns = 7;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        if (isConsecutiveFour(values[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkVertical(int [][] values)
{
    int numberOfRows = 6;
    int numberOfColumns = 7;

    for (int j =0; j < numberOfColumns; j++)
    {
        int [] column = new int[numberOfRows];

        if (isConsecutiveFour(column))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for diagonals that start from the four corners, or any possible diagonal?

Comment: Im looking for any possible diagonals

Answer (score 0):

For checking diagonals, for the \ diagonals you will increment both row and column.  For the / diagonals, you will increment row and decrement column.  Otherwise they will be quite similar to the ones you have already implemented.

Comment: Have a triple nested loop, with outermost iterating over the rows, middle one over the columns.  Look at pattern[row][col].  The innermost loop will then run ii from 1 to 3, checking that pattern[row + ii][col + ii] matches pattern[row][col]. If all four match, it's a four in a row.  If any doesn't match or if row + ii or col + ii is too large for your array, break to the next column to check.  Similarly,  for the backwards diagonal you would use pattern[row - ii][col + ii] but need to check for row - ii being too small.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check your `checkVertical`again, you create a array of correct length, but never assign any values out of `values[][]` to it.

What you do in `isConsecutiveFour` might lead you to your goal. Let me explain what you do in order to help you understand what you have to do:

You start at every possible position in a row, and check if the following 3 are the same. Then you do the same for every row.
If you dont check if the next in the row (`values[c+1]` which is basically `values[r][c+1]`) but the next in column (`values[r+1][c]`) or in vertical line (`values[r+1][c+1]`/`values[r+1][c-1]`) are the same, you get the other patterns.

My tip: get rid of the different functions, iterate over all possible positions [r][c] and try something like this:

```
if (c<numberOfColumns-3){ //check here if this is inside your array bounds
  if (values[r][c+1]==values[r][c] && 
      values[r][c+2]==values[r][c] &&
      values[r][c+3]==values[r][c]) {
    //horizontal pattern, starting at [r][c]
  }
}
```

I think it should be easy to figure out how the code should look like for the other patterns.